# how can i re-arrange options on highchart grid using API

Tags: highcharts

How can i re-arrange the options that show on the high-charts, the first option is the print charts followed by various download options, how can i make download png as the first option followed by others.

I tried to see and customise the exporting.js but could not make it work, any suggestions would be appreciated, Thanks.

Comment: Any sample on fiddle would be appreciated to help you!

Comment: Use [`exportin.buttons.contextButton.menuItems`](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#exporting.buttons.contextButton.menuItems) to change list of displayed options.